# htaccess simple redirect doesnt work

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I need to redirect using htaccess every request which points at:
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=293&Itemid=387
to this url:
http://www.otherdomain.com

I've try to do it by:

```
redirect /index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=293&Itemid=387 http://www.otherdomain.com
```

But it doesnt work. So I need Your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use mod_rewrite for this stuff.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=293&Itemid=387$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /? [L,R=302,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Yes i found this solution to:) (You've got /\ from me), but there is still one problem the GET params are send to newdomain and it makes 404. So next question is how to clear GET params?

Comment: Get params should not be going because of `/?` in the target URL. As long as target URL has a trailing `?` it will strip out all the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone may need to extend my answer but you'll be looking to do something along the lines of:-

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  index.php?option=$1 [R=301,L]
```

The rule will require a regular expression so the server can compare the request.

Comment: But i want to redirect not to rewrite, and only this one concrete url not every which match to regex

Comment: The above will 301 redirect... Not everything can be done with a Redirect 301 directive, especially with regex. My answer will be what you require, it just requires an expert at regex to handle each query parameter for you in the request.

Comment: I dont know if You understand my problem. I want something like this: if i write 'www.mydomain.php?parameter=doesnt_matter' in my browser htaccess should redirect me to 'www.mynextdomain.php' but if  i write address 'www.mydomain.php?parameter=something' htaccess should not redirect me. And the problem is that htaccess doesn't see GET parameters in regex - ?i think?

Comment: Yes, I understood your problem as you detailed in your original question but in your comment, you say you now want to redirect to a different domain (which is also do-able from the RewriteRule above incidentally)? If it is always blog id=293, Itemid=387 which serves the same content that you wish to only redirect, then this is possible by extending what I've started in my answer - although a RewriteCond may also be required.

Comment: Yes it should redirect to different domain - my mistake(edited). But i still doesn't have answer how to do it:(

Comment: anubhava was exactly the member I was hoping to step in for this one. Follow what he says, was indeed the Rewrite Condition required as well :)